# search for ClientID client-side or server-side?

Tags: clientid

I understand that I currently can't use `<a onclick="alert('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>')"` directly because I need to access it in a table cell in a table in the EditTemplate of a DataList inside a UserControl.

That said, I need to recursively check the controls to get the ClientID, should it be done
   **client-side**:  `alert(getMyElement('TextBox1').id)`, where getMyElement checks all elements of the form and returns the control with the id...or
**server-side**:  `alert('<%=FindElement(dlDataList, "TextBox1").ClientID%>')` where FindElement is a base page function that checks the controls of the first param for an element with an id of the second param and returns that control 
?

I'm figuring the client-side would be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always go with server side for this case.  Otherwise you're traversing the entire DOM with each row - depending on the size, it could be a memory hog.  Server side takes almost no resources for this.