# inline or databind expressions in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, inline, data-binding

it's a related question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589548/search-for-clientid-client-side-or-server-side), but merits its' own question.
If I need to call a server-side function inside my EditItemTemplate of my DataList, should I use `<%=ServerSideFunction(...)%>` or `<%#ServerSideFunction(...)%>`?
Both work since there is a databind going on with the DataList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to bind data use : `<%#ServerSideFunction(...)%>`

If you want to write(<% Response.Write( ) %>) something use : `<%=ServerSideFunction(...)%>`

Read this question : [what are the <% %> constructs called in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525424/what-are-the-constructs-called-in-asp-net/1525505#1525505)

Comment: I use the ServerSideFunction to get a ClientID of a TextBox to call a javascript function.  I guess that would go under binding?